# Div stretch then wrap around other floated div

Tags: css, css-float

I'm struggling trying to get the behavior that I want with CSS.

I created a JSFiddle here that shows my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/c2Snd/

I want my #left div's width to stretch, but only as far as the #right div.

Basically, I want my #left divs to wrap around my #right dive just like text would. So in my JSFiddle, the top 2 red boxes' width would be 50%, then the bottom red box's width would be 100%.

Comment: you shouldn't use the id for more than one div... use class instead

Comment: Did you try nesting your right div inside your left div? Also setting overflow: hidden, and removing using min-height: 100px instead of just explicit height: 100px? Like so: http://jsfiddle.net/5d52h/ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you just about have it.. confused:
http://jsfiddle.net/BCBd2/1/

Comment: by the way, you should be using classes for the `#left` divs, as there are more than one. ID's should be unique.

Comment: Is there any way to accomplish this WITHOUT using `overflow: hidden;`? I need to have an absolutely positioned menu appear inside the red boxes that exceeds the height of the box, so I can't use `overflow: hidden;`.

Answer (score 0):

Well I do not know if there are any shortcuts to doing this, but try this re-Fiddle.. http://jsfiddle.net/c2Snd/1/
To make something like this you will need to use percentage in width and border-width, so they are proportional to eachother.

Answer (score 0):

Does it serves your purpose?

http://jsfiddle.net/c2Snd/2/