# How can I have display: block; elements wrap around a floated element like text would?

Tags: css, css-float, sidebar

I've done a bit of Googling and found a number of references to the problem I'm trying to solve, but all suggest the same solution that I can't use. The problem is that I have a sidebar floated right and some divs that need to expand to the width left over from the sidebar, but then expand to the full width when the sidebar is no longer preventing them from doing so.

The jsfiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/qdk3n/

The solution found elsewhere is to apply `overflow: hidden;` to the `.left` items. This achieves exactly the effect I want: divs that share horizontal space with the sidebar only expand as far as the sidebar, but additional divs expand to the full allowed width. Unfortunately, there will be an absolutely positioned item inside the left divs that exceeds the size of the div and will get cropped if I apply `overflow: hidden;`, so I can't use that. Is there any way to accomplish what I'm trying to do without using `overflow: hidden;`?

Note: I don't know the size of either the sidebar or any of the left divs prior to page render time, and I cannot use Javascript in any way, shape, or form (since this is meant to work for users with JS disabled). The only dimension I can set in all of this is the width of the sidebar; the divs need to be fluid and I can't arbitrarily choose some number of them to only extend part of the way.

Also note: I've seen this: [Div stretch then wrap around other floated div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10129818/div-stretch-then-wrap-around-other-floated-div). It is exactly what I'm trying to do, but the only real solution is the `overflow: hidden;` property, and I can't use that.

Comment: Can you give more details about "there will be an absolutely positioned item inside the left divs that exceeds the size of the div"? Ideally, an example.

Comment: Check out the jsfiddle and add `overflow: hidden;` to the `.left` CSS. The effect that results is exactly what I want to have happen, except I also need to not hide overflowing content... so I can't really use `overflow: hidden;`

Comment: Is there anything wrong with this? http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/qdk3n/54/

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to attach to a `a:hover ul` selector, which will be inside the contents of the div. If it was just a matter of putting in one `position: absolute;` div, it wouldn't be a problem, but it needs to be a child of another element inside the styled div. It's a creative solution, though, and I'll be keeping it in mind for the future.

Answer (score 0):

Unless i missed something, i don't think it is possible to achieve exactly what you ask for.

The reason `overflow: hidden;` changes the behavior of the (`display: block;`) elements is something called "Block Formatting Context", which you can read about here;

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/block_formatting_context
http://www.communitymx.com/content/article.cfm?cid=6BC9D

Technically, you can keep the elements `display: block;` and have them respect the floated sidebar, by floating your left divs as well, but this will unlikely have the effect you want.

However, any inline content inside your left divs are going to respect the floated sidebar, so i don't really see the need for the divs to behave like you describe (maybe elaborate on your reasons behind it to get more constructive feedback).

Comment: The left-floated divs have styles that I don't want to extend underneath the sidebar. I want the left-float divs to maintain their own style and leave the sidebar to it's own styles; things like borders and backgrounds need to stay within their allotted horizontal space. I know _why_ `overflow: hidden;` works, but I was hoping for an alternative.